# How do I print columns with specified form using AWK?

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a csv file with data like below:

```
James Cameron,8415664,JCameron@outlook.com
Jimmy Fallon,97546444,JFallon@gmail.com
Aron Kuo,03446466,N/a
```

I've used

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /Jimmy Fallon/ {print $1, $2}' name.csv
```

to output the first two column with matching name, but now I what print result in specified form as `Name:<$1>, Phone number:<$2>`   How do I achieve this?

Comment: You probably mean `$1 == "Jimmy Fallon"` instead of `$1 ~ /Jimmy Fallon/` so you don't match on `John Jimmy Falloncamp`

Comment: "John Jimmy Falloncamp" LOL

Answer (score 3):

Try `printf`:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /Jimmy Fallon/ {printf "Name:%s, Phone Number:%s\n",$1,$2}' name.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use strings in `print`:

```
awk -F, '$1 ~ /Jimmy Fallon/ {print "Name:" $1, "Phone number" $2}' name.csv
```

Comment: Oh, problem solved thank you

Comment: you can accept the answer as a solution .. so that other's facing similar issue can browse directly to the solution

Comment: This won't match the desired output exactly.